# Dependency conflict logback and log4j when using LogCaptor

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I am migration to springboot 3, and in my test I use LogCaptor.
it seems that Logcaptor embeds Logback , and I have to exclude log4j transitive dependency ,that's what I did :

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
        <artifactId>logcaptor</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- exclusion log4j déjà dans spring boot starter pour les main IT-->
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I have the following error when launching tests :

```
    Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=KeychainStore
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

and then :

```
    SLF4J: Actual provider is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider@31be6b49]

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SLF4J Logger implementation should be of the type [ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger] but found [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger].

    At nl.altindag.log.util.ValidationUtils.requireLoggerOfType(ValidationUtils.java:36)
    at nl.altindag.log.LogCaptor.<init>(LogCaptor.java:57)
    at nl.altindag.log.LogCaptor.forClass(LogCaptor.java:84)
```

i want to highlight that I have this problem when I migrated from LogCaptor 2.6.0 to version 2.9.0 , here is my dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
        <artifactId>logcaptor</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- exclusion log4j already in spring boot starter for tests main IT-->
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

when I change the version of LogCaptor to 2.7.10 , I have the following error :

```
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/spi/LoggingEventAware
```

I did a man Dependency:tree and I have this result :

```
     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.17.1:compile
```

I add the dependency tree for the module that contains the test that fails:

```
    [INFO] +- io.github.hakky54:logcaptor:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.7:test
[INFO] |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.7:test
```

I put the version of SLF4j to version <slf4j.version>2.0.7</slf4j.version>

i have the following error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler

at nl.altindag.log.LogCaptor.<init>(LogCaptor.java:76)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems to be a classpath issue where some jars have a different version. Can you share the full mvn: dependency tree output?